# PHP file parse--problems with last item in row

Tags: php, parsing, explode

I have a text file on the server that is generated from a database export.  I have no control over that file.  I am trying to parse it in PHP to get some of the data to display on a web page.  When I try to search for the last item in a row, it can't find it.

Here is a portion of the text file:

```
ERMHDR  8.2 2017-02-02  Project admin   Primavera Admin dbxDatabaseNoName   Project Management  USD
%T  CURRTYPE
%F  curr_id decimal_digit_cnt   curr_symbol decimal_symbol  digit_group_symbol  pos_curr_fmt_type   neg_curr_fmt_type   curr_type   curr_short_name group_digit_cnt base_exch_rate
%R  1   2   $   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Dollar  USD 3   1
%R  10  2   $   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Argentine Peso  ARS 3   3.077
%R  11  2   A$  .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Australian Dollar   AUST    3   1.208
%R  13  2   R$  .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Brazilian Real  BRL 3   2.014
%R  14  2   £   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  British Pound   U.K.    3   0.501762
%R  15  2   CA$ .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Canadian Dollar CAD 3   1.10573
%R  16  2   Y   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Chinese Yuan    CNY 3   7.694
%R  17  2   €   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  EURO    EUR 3   0.739088
%R  20  2   HK$ .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Hong Kong Dollar    HKD 3   7.81967
%R  21  2   Rs  .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Indian Rupee    INR 3   40.67
%R  23  2   ¥   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Japanese Yen    JPY 3   120.167
%R  24  2   K   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Korean Won  KRW 3   924.743
%R  25  2   N$  .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Mexican Peso    MXN 3   10.7938
%R  26  2   R   .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Russian Rouble  RUB 3   25.8085
%R  28  2   Sk  .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Swedish Krona   SEK 3   6.80579
%R  29  2   kr  .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Swiss Franc CHF 3   1.21864
%R  30  2   NIS .   ,   #1.1    (#1.1)  Israel Shekel   ILS 3   3.96384
```

This works perfectly.  It finds the line that has "10" as the second value and returns the row number.

```
<?php
    $txt_file    = file_get_contents('sandbox/uploads/sample3.xer');
    $rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
    array_shift($rows);

    foreach($rows as $row => $data)
    {
        $row_data = explode("\t", $data);

        if($row_data[1] == "10"){ //THIS IS THE LINE GIVING ME PROBLEMS
            echo 'Row #: ';
            echo $row;
            echo '     ';
            echo $row_data[1];
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

However, if I change the indicated row to this, it does not work.

```
if($row_data[1] == "CURRTYPE"){
```

I think the issue is that when I exploded the file, I somehow put a special character at the end of each line and I need to include that character in my if statement, but I can not figure out what that special character is.  I have tried adding a space, \n, \t.

Can anyone help???

Comment: Have you tried `trim($row_data[1]) == 'CURRTYPE'`?

Comment: Justinas...you are my hero.  thank you so much.

Comment: More specifically, it wouldn't hurt to grab `$row_data[1]`, check its length, and see what the actual character is. It'll probably help later.

Comment: kungphu...i will try that.  It has been driving me nuts for the last several hours.

Comment: The line breaks are probably `\r\n` and not just `\n`?

Comment: CBroe...that did not work, but the trimming that Justinas suggested did.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Matthew  - how did you come along - do you have solved the issues. Look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim` to remove any additional chars at start or end of string (e.g. whitespace).

```
if (strcasecmp(trim($row_data[1]), 'currtype') === 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to read it with file. This will turn each line as an array.
I tried it on your text portion and got all lines.
and with explode(' ', THE LINE YOU WANT);
will give you each word in that line

```
$test_file = file('sample3.xer');
$line_4 = $test_file[4];
$string_line = explode(' ', $line_4);
foreach ($string_line as $k => $v) {
if (!empty($v)) echo $v.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I may have to use this technique later on.